# mongoose detect insert vs update during upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How do I know if the model was insert or update when using `findOneAndUpdate` in mongoose?

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $setOnInsert: setOnInsert, $set: set }, { upsert: true }, function (err, doc) {
});
```

Is it only possible by setting a flag during `$setOnInsert` and `$set`? (Would be good if I could avoid this.)